# Crear archivos .php con fopen()

Tags: php, html, web, archivo

Estoy Intentando esto:

```
<a href="
<?php
$fh = fopen($p['n'].php, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
if($fh)
{
$code ="
<?php
//codigo combinado con html nada complejo incluí php para manejar sesiones
?>";
echo fwrite($file,$code); 
    fclose($file); 
}?>"></a>
```

El problema es que evalúa el código dentro de `$code` en vez de simplemente pasarlo como un string

Comment: Deberías escapar los < y > de $code precediendo con \, creo.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor dar un poco más de detalles sobre tu código? ¿Qué hace? ¿Qué esperas obtener? ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Qué es `$p['n'].php`?  ¿Dentro de ese archivo habría otro archivo referido en una variable `$file`?  ... ¿O hay un script que hackea el sistema? A mi me parece una forma algo peligrosa de manejar archivos. Sería interesante que explicaras si es posible qué alcance tendría tu programa.

Comment: combinado con html nada complejo incluí php para manejar sesiones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tengo 2 errores que están al momento de ingresar el `string` en `$code`

> 1. Olvidé que para que el string sea guardado sin evaluarse se debe hacer con una sola coma así:
>
> `$code = 'hola';`
>
> no con doble comilla así:
>
> `$code= "hola";`
>
> 2. Como son varias lineas se debe hacer con EOD así:
>
> `$code = <<<'EOD'
>   codigo
>   con
>   muchas
>   lineas
>   EOD;`

Así es como logré hacer que el contenido de `$code` no fuera evaluado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con el siguiente código:

```
$nombre_archivo = 'archivo.php';

$mensaje = "El Archivo $nombre_archivo se ha creado";

if($archivo = fopen($nombre_archivo, "a"))
{
    if(fwrite($archivo, date("d m Y H:m:s"). " ". $mensaje. "\n"))
    {
        echo "Se ha ejecutado correctamente";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ha habido un problema al crear el archivo";
    }

    fclose($archivo);
}
```